# Why was this non-programming question migrated from SU to SO?

Tags: discussion, migration, networking

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832505/simulating-a-bad-internet-connection

This guy was looking for a way to use a PC to simulate a bad network connection. I provided him with a way to use a PC to simulate a bad network connection. No programming was involved in the question or answer.

It seems like SU is a better fit than SO for this question and answer. Why was it migrated?

I could almost see migrating it to SF, but he was asking about PCs and devices like you'd find on a small/home network, not the kind of enterprise/data center stuff that is usually on-topic for SF.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to ask the people who voted to migrate it …

Comment: *migrated to stackoverflow.com by Scott Chamberlain, Randolph West, Renan, Gareth, Diogo 1 hour ago*

Comment: I can only hazard a guess, but I imagine because he's *testing a device he's been programming / developing himself*. As a metaphor, I'm sure un-clogging a toilet is a valuable skill and many non-plumbers could tell me how to do such, but asking a plumber directly has a very high chance of getting me very accurate information since it's a part of their profession, to a degree. Testing hardware/software falls under SO just as much as SU, if not moreso - This is one of the areas that the sites overlap, and 5 people made the call that the OP would get better answers from SO :)